# Confusion about thread synchronization when two threads call the same method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, blocking, messenger

I've created a Messenger library and I've made it thread safe so it can be shared around between threads without worry. I achieve this mostly using the Monitor class.

I have a Logout routine which can take some time to complete because it tries to wait for transactions taking place before it shuts down the socket etc. It's asynchronous and has Begin/End methods, but for this example we'll just pretend it's synchronous.

What if two threads call Logout, one right after another? What should I be doing with the second thread?

Currently I block (using Monitor.Wait to wait for a Pulse from the first thread) until the first logout completes and then throw a AlreadyLoggedOutException.

I've also toyed with having a LogoutInProgress exception thrown if Logout is called but a logout is already taking place.

Both seem to have advantages and disadvantages, but I'd like to know what other people think is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the best option out of the two you mentioned, depends on how you want your library to behave.

I would not throw the exception to the consumer and simply fire the end logout async event/method for both of the threads when the actual logout completes. Which synchronization primitive you should be using to achieve this depends on the design of your method/library. Maybe if you share more details on the Begin End method you mentioned, i'll be able to suggest better.

This option would be easier to program against.

Comment: The asynchronous side of it isn't important. What you're saying the Logout method should just return (void) for both of them AFTER the logout takes place without any exception?

Comment: If both of them intend to logout on the same client and operation is idempotent then there is no point in throwing exception.

Comment: The logic with the exception makes sense thanks. But you truly believe that both logout calls should "block" until the actual logout has completed? In theory I could just return from the second logout, since the fist logout is guaranteed to succeed at some point. The problem I see with that is that it would give the caller the illusion of the Logout being completed when infact it is still taking place.

Comment: @NoPyGod how is logout guaranteed? What if you get a network error? And the illusion of being completed is a more serious problem.

Comment: Logout is guaranteed because it's simply a matter of disconnecting the socket. If the socket produces an exception while logging out, it is swallowed because the user is already asking to be disconnected. But yes the illusion of completion is also something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd option: The second thread trying to Logout could detect, that a logout already happened and do nothing. If the contract of "Logout" is "either ensure that the user is logged out, or throw" then you should indeed make Logout idempotent.

However if you cannot tolerate multiple logouts because that would be a logic error somehow you should throw an exception.